# How to capture another village?

Tags: realm-of-empires

How am I supposed to get a second village? Do I have to capture a Rebel Village, or do I have to find an empty spot in the map to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take over *another village*, *rebel village* or *abandoned village* with the [governor](http://roe.wikia.com/wiki/Governor).

---

A village can be taken over only when a governor is sent along with the troops. Only a Governor is capable of convincing the Council of Elders, of the defending village, to hand over the village into better hands.

Only one Governor is required to take over a village but you need to attack a village several times in order to capture it because a governor will only lower the Council Of Elders approval rate by between 14% to17% (random) in one attack. Once the approval rate for the current owner falls below 50%, the village becomes yours.

Only send 1 governor with an attack; sending more will not have a greater effect. If you have more than 1 governor in a village, you can send multiple attacks, each with a governor.

An example of a typical attack to take over a village :

Multiple waves are required to take over another village, all arriving as close together as possible:
Wave 1) Spies : To ascertain the strength of the defender.

Accordingly send a clearing attack. It is better to send another spy attack just before your clearing attack lands just in case someone has supported the village in the mean time.

Wave 2) Clearing attack - Knights + rams + trebuchets (target=towers)
Rams and Trebs to be used if the inactive villages is a built up village.

Wave 3) Governor (1)  + Knights

Wave 4) Governor ( 1 )+ Knights

Wave 5) Governor ( 1)  + Knights
put a time gap of 10 minutes before the 4th Governor hits the village....incase the 3rd Gov. takes over the village you have time to cancel the last attack.

Wave 6) Governor ( 1)  - w/support (infantry) 
The Governor that lowers the approval below 50% stays in the village along with the troops.

Preferably try taking a village near to your villages. The faster you are , more are your chances to successfully take over a village.